# Find a primitive function

Tags: analysis

Does there anyone who knows how to find a primitive solution to:

cosx(1/sinx)

I know the answer is ln|lnx| but i do not know how to get there.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't get $\ln|\ln x|$.  You do get $\ln|\text{something}| + \text{constant}.$
$$
\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\, dx = \int \frac 1 {\sin x} \Big( \cos x\,dx\Big) = \int \frac 1 u \, du = \cdots
$$